# Ubuntu installed without wifi

Tags: wifi-direct

​[image: Photo of screen displaying a shell]
​
I don't know the manufacturer.

The command requested in the comments `sudo lshw -C network` shows:

```
description: Network controller Product: RTL8821CE Wireless network adapter
```

Comment: Without wifi it will be hard for you to copy paste to here, unless you have ethernet.  But you could [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1437997/edit) your question with the output of `sudo dmidecode -t system -t baseboard` and `sudo lshw -C network`.  Any details that would could give us more could help.

Comment: @Terrance the first command didn't work. The second one showed up with "description: Network controller
Product: RTL8821CE Wireless network adapter "

Comment: This means I have to install a realtek network thing?

Comment: You would need some sort of network connection to install it, but yes it would be `sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms`

Comment: @Terrance, it worked! You're invited to my Halloween party.

Comment: @Bungaaa Could you please 'Accept' Terrance's answer below by clicking on the check or tick mark? This way future readers of your problem will easily see that a successful resolution has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment earlier, your system uses the `rtl8821ce` driver.  To install it have a network connection connected then run:

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```